# Python: adding calculated list elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
list_1 = [['good', 2, 2], ['bad', 2, 2], ['be', 1, 1], ['brown', 1, 3]]
```

I would like to add new element to the inner list by summing the two numbers. So my list should look like

```
list_1 = [['good', 2, 2, 4], ['bad', 2, 2, 4], ['be', 1, 1, 2], ['brown', 1, 2, 3]]
```

How do I add insert new element into list by adding a column? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_1 = [['good', 2, 2], ['bad', 2, 2], ['be', 1, 1], ['brown', 1, 3]]
print(list_1)
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    list_1[i]+=[list_1[i][1]+list_1[i][2]]
print(list_1)
```

Comment: No need for the counter i - better to iterate directly using in

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I hadn't thought of it. Sebastian's way is more efficient

Answer (score 4):

```
for lst in list_1:
    lst.append(lst[1]+lst[2])
```

Comment: This only gives the last list

Comment: @agf, not with the first element of the array being a string

Comment: @Walkerneo I meant `lst.append(sum(lst[1:]))` :)

Comment: @Pradeep: It modifies elements of the list `list_1` inplace. The result is `list_1`, not `lst`.

Comment: True, but we're not playing code golf here, just trying to give someone something they can understand and use.

Comment: @Walkerneo It wasn't an attempt at golfing, but generalization, in case his real use case is something like `[['good', 2, 2], ['bad', 2, 2, 4]]` or `[['good', 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['bad', 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` where you can't or wouldn't want to just chain additions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Iterate over your list of lists.
2. For each list in your list of lists,
3. Compute your new element, and append it to the list.